# How to get current element in JasperReports when using conditionalExpression with styles?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to make text in the textValue to be red when the numeric value of the cell is less than zero. Currently my configuration is like this:

```
<style name="RedText">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{col1}.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == -1]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#FF0000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

I have more cells (col2, col3, col4 ...) that I would need to apply this red text style. Is it possible to make it universal for current value, etc. col*?

Comment: No, you can't do it in *jrxml*. You can try to apply style from *Java* code. Another way - try to modify the source code of *JR*. But looks strange for me that style is obtaining data of control

Comment: I have a new thought how to create a hack. I'll check tonight :)

Comment: Ok, share this hack with us :)

Comment: I added a new "hard hack" solution. I hope you will like it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The standard/classical way without using Java code

It is impossible without using *Java* code. In your case you need to create the new style for each field and apply this concrete style for *textField* element with *conditionExpression* contains the value of concrete *field*.

In common case the expression of *textField* can be complex, the same is true for the *conditionExpression*. The style does not know to which control it belongs. We can't operate with value of abstract field (parameter/variable), the engine need the concrete names to calculate expression.

### Using Java API

Is it possible to solve the task applying style with *JasperReports Java API*. For example:

```
JRDesignStyle boldStyle = new JRDesignStyle();
boldStyle.setName("Sans_Bold");
boldStyle.setFontName("DejaVu Sans");
boldStyle.setFontSize(12);
boldStyle.setBold(true);
// ...
textField.setStyle(boldStyle);
JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
expression.setText("$F{col1}");
textField.setExpression(expression);
```

### Using backdoor or "yes we like to hack"

Look at the beatiful class in *Java* is *Map*, it so invaluable in *JasperReports*. It can help us to crack this task.

1. We need parameter of *Map* type for storing the value of field (it will be abstract field - *"col<sub>n</sub>"*)
2. We need to enable applying style during resolving expression of a *textField*. The propery 
   *[net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled)* will help to enable this feature.
3. We need some *Java* method for putting value in to the *Map* (as a storage of a *"col<sub>n</sub>"*) which returns the value we just put. The *[Map.put(K key, V value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-)* is not good for this purpose. I wrote the small Utility class with wrapper over *Map.put* method.

#### The datasouce

The using of simple *csv* datasource is enough for this example. I like this kind of datasource for testing and debugging.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
1,2,3,9,-5
-2,6,-3,4,1
2,-2,-2,7,-3
8,3,4,-5,6
```

The name of data adapter for this datasource in the example below is *numbers.csv*. The first line from the file is skipped - it is contains the column's name.

#### Java code

It is a very simple utility class

```
public class Storage {

    public static Integer add(Map<String, Integer> map, String key, Integer value) {
        map.put(key, value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

#### Report template

1. The import for our utitlity class should be added for using it.
2. For correct resolving expression of *conditional style* we need to use in expression some parameter or some variable (you can check the source code of *JasperReports*). I'll add some fake variable for using in *conditionExpression*
3. We need to put the value of *"col<sub>n</sub>"* to the *Map* and then  use this value in *conditional style*. In this case we don't need to know the name of field we are checking in *conditional style*. The parameter will be used for storing *Map*.
4. We need place and draw the value of *"col<sub>n</sub>"* in two runs. We can use fake invisible *textField* to put the field's value to the *Map* and another *textField* to show value with applying conditional style. The positions and sizes of this *textField*s are same - one above the other.

Our condition will be like this:

```
<style name="ColoredText">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[(((Integer)$P{STORAGE}.get($P{KEY})) < 0)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="blue"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[(((Integer)$P{STORAGE}.get($P{KEY})) > 0)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="green"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

There is no *field* in *conditionExpression* and it works :)

The *jrxml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Apply style withou name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="numbers.csv"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled" value="true"/>
    <import value="some.package.Storage"/>
    <style name="ColoredText">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{STORAGE}.get($P{KEY}) == null && !"null".equalsIgnoreCase($V{FAKE})]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#CC0000"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[(((Integer)$P{STORAGE}.get($P{KEY})) < 0) && !"null".equalsIgnoreCase($V{FAKE})]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#0037FF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[(((Integer)$P{STORAGE}.get($P{KEY})) > 0) && !"null".equalsIgnoreCase($V{FAKE})]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#00BA00"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="Fake">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[!"null".equalsIgnoreCase($V{FAKE})]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="STORAGE" class="java.util.Map">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.HashMap()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="KEY" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["key"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <field name="col1" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col2" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col3" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col4" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col5" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="FAKE" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA["FAKE"]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement style="Fake" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[some.package.Storage.add($P{STORAGE}, $P{KEY}, $F{col1})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement style="ColoredText" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{STORAGE}.get($P{KEY})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement style="Fake" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[some.package.Storage.add($P{STORAGE}, $P{KEY}, $F{col2})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement style="ColoredText" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{STORAGE}.get($P{KEY})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement style="Fake" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[some.package.Storage.add($P{STORAGE}, $P{KEY}, $F{col3})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement style="ColoredText" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{STORAGE}.get($P{KEY})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement style="Fake" x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[some.package.Storage.add($P{STORAGE}, $P{KEY}, $F{col4})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement style="ColoredText" x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{STORAGE}.get($P{KEY})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement style="Fake" x="400" y="0" width="140" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[some.package.Storage.add($P{STORAGE}, $P{KEY}, $F{col5})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement style="ColoredText" x="400" y="0" width="140" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{STORAGE}.get($P{KEY})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The green color is used for positive numbers and blue - for negative. The red color is using to indicate algorithm's problems.

#### Output result

The generated *pdf* with help of *JRPdfExporter*:

[image: The generated pdf]

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.

Comment: "The Map.put(K key, V value) is not good for this purpose." What's wrong with just map.put ? I've tried your example and it works fine for me by using a Variable set to java.util.HashMap.

`<variable name="STORAGE" class="java.util.HashMap" calculation="System">
  <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.HashMap()]]>`

"correct resolving expression of conditional style we need to use in expression some parameter or some variable" Isn't `style name="ColoredText"` already referring to a Parameter in your example and as such fulfilling the need to refer to a Parameter ?