# Conditional Style Based on TextField Value

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to set a style based on the textField value for many textFields. I need to do it generic, not setting each $F{name_of_field} style for each textField cell.
is it possible in jaspersoft studio?

Comment: Maybe this post help you: [How to get current element in JasperReports when using conditionalExpression with styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40255312/876298)