# Conditional Formatting according to value in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to know if there's a way to re-use conditional formatting for several textFields each one associated to different parameters.

Right now I´ve manage to do it by writing a custom style for each one, but it´s a nightmare to mantain.

Here´s what I´ve got:

```xml
<style name="style_door" mode="Transparent" forecolor="#000000">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{door}.equals("REPLACE")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Transparent" forecolor="#CC0000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{door}.equals("REPAIR")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Transparent" forecolor="#FF9900"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{door}.equals("OK")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Transparent" forecolor="#009900"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>

<style name="style_window" mode="Transparent" forecolor="#000000">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{window}.equals("REPLACE")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Transparent" forecolor="#CC0000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{window}.equals("REPAIR")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Transparent" forecolor="#FF9900"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{window}.equals("OK")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Transparent" forecolor="#009900"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>



<textField>
    <reportElement style="style_door" x="112" y="26" width="53" height="13" uuid="07eacbda-9ed8-418e-9f97-937bb44ca976"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font size="7"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{door}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>

<textField>
    <reportElement style="style_window" x="112" y="26" width="53" height="13" uuid="07eacbda-9ed8-418e-9f97-937bb44ca976"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font size="7"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{window}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Notice that the 2 styles are the same, it just change the condition, because it should match a different parameter. And then I apply the style to each textField.

Is there a way I can write a single style and the condition be matched with the value of the element associated to? Or could I pass the element's value as an argument to the style and be used in the condition?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255312/how-to-get-current-element-in-jasperreports-when-using-conditionalexpression-wit) to a similar question from a while back.

I've done some testing and contradictory to the answer linked above I managed to do it without a additional class. All other statements, especially regarding evaluation time and style.evaluation.time still apply. Please read the explanations linked in the answer above.

Example for your application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.20.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Apply style withou name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c7e9565b-28fb-4eeb-b6e0-cd9bd8460722">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled" value="true"/>
    <style name="ColoredText">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[((String)$V{STORAGE}.get("key")).equals("OK")]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#009900"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[((String)$V{STORAGE}.get("key")).equals("REPAIR")]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#FF9900"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[((String)$V{STORAGE}.get("key")).equals("REPLACE")]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#CC0000"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="door" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="window" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="STORAGE" class="java.util.Map" calculation="System">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.HashMap()]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="21">
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="d9392134-e246-41c7-8c66-9d21f06e0465"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{STORAGE}.put("key", $P{window}) == null ? null : null]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="ColoredText" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="fda2f3f5-fe34-424e-8af9-b4f0111936b2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{STORAGE}.get("key")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="6dcf014e-ffc9-47be-81ee-04f1912d3be2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{STORAGE}.put("key", $P{door}) == null ? null : null]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="ColoredText" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="54cc1367-8387-4fc0-be00-5ba789cce7e9"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{STORAGE}.get("key")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```